# How can I find out where value-of function is finding it's value in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<tr>
 <td colSpan="2" align="center" width="46%" height="15">
     Number: <xsl:value-of select="substring(//number, 7,7)"/>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Where is `//number` stored and how can I see where it's value is generated in first place? I can't find this inside `xslt` code, so I believe it is somewhere outside of it and that this is the path to te variable named `number`? If that is true, where can I find the the whole path?

**EDIT**

Is this the line where that node is initialized?

```
<xsl:variable name="number"><xsl:value-of select="substring(//number, 7,7)"/></xsl:variable>
```

Comment: `//number` is any node (tag) called 'number'. The `//` means it searches from the root.

Comment: `number` refers to an element named `number` in your XML. What does your XML look like?

Comment: The part I have added in `EDIT` is the only linewhere `name="number"` exists

Comment: The code containing the information would be in the XML file that is being transformed. It would be literally called 'number', e.g.: `<number>3</number>`.

Comment: @AntonH I didn't know the way that works, thank you!

Comment: From [Wikipedia XSLT page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT): "XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) is a language for transforming XML documents into other XML documents,[1] or other formats". You need a base XML document that will be transformed.

Comment: I've got that one, but there is no `<number>...</number>` in it, so I am confused...

Comment: No `<number>` tag in the base XML document ?

Comment: Yes. Tell me, is the `xml` doc that is being transformed the one that is referenced in `<xsl:include href=""/>` tag?

Comment: No. The XML doc specifies the XSLT doc, not the other way round. I would recomment going through a beginners XSLT tutorial, such as [W3school.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp), or another if you know one.

Comment: Okay, thank you, sorry for wasting your time.